# Rails model is not setting attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3

am very new on rails development

Rails 3.2.13 / ruby 1.9.3

I have this model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :content, :title
    attr_accessor :testing

    def asignar
        title = "hey"
    end
end
```

And then when i go to the rails console:

```
irb(main):004:0* post = Post.new
=> #<Post id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):005:0> post.asignar
=> "hey"
irb(main):006:0> post.title
=> nil
```

Is this normal?, do I have always to save the object so I can be able to get attributes?

Comment: `self.title = 'hey'`; `title = "hey"` is setting the local variable `title`, not the attribute.

Comment: As Lee says, when writing to an attribute of the model, you should use `self.title`. When reading the attribute it's customary to use only the attribute name `title`, but `self.title` or `self[:title]` would also work.

Comment: Lee Jarvis that's exactly the answer, I know this is a very silly, still i think that could be useful for others, why dont you make your comment an answer so i can mark it as accepted :) thanks

Comment: Looks like hyngyn got there first. His answer is also correct, thanks  though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def asignar
    self.title = "hey"
end
```